# Lookup a value that matches a key in one column then apply that as a key to return a value from a third column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have values in columns G and N that have the same values, but not in the same order, so if column G and N matches, then return column L to column A. I am getting the wrong values from column L in column A.

What other information is needed besides formula below?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N2,$G$2:$N$413,6,FALSE),"")
```

```
Col a      Col b    Col G    Col L   Col M    Col N
    ID     CoID     Items    ItemsID ParentID Items1
    45     1        Apple    45      1        Apple
```

Comment: i'm sorry, which menu control can i use to build a table ?

Comment: thank you for that site, it's very helpful. it'd be nice if sof has a table fill in template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are trying to find the ColumnL value in the same row as you find the ColumnN value I’d suggest an [INDEX](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) [MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) combination – similar to VLOOKUP but more powerful (eg can ‘look to the left’, which VLOOKUP can’t).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(L:L,MATCH(G2,N:N,0)),"")
```

MATCH looks for the *position* where G2 is found in ColumnN so that is the row number for the ColumnL value you want returned.

Comment: YES YOU DID IT ~!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!!!!!!!! I can't bump it up the point because i don't have enough points but i'll come back when i do.